# How to sync a salt execution module with non-python dependencies

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am currently transforming a perl / bash tool into a salt module and I am wondering how I should sync the non-python parts of this module to my minions.

I want to run salt agent-less and ideally the dependencies would by synced automatically alongside the module itself once its called via salt-ssh.

But it seems that only python scripts get synced. Any thoughts for a nice and clean solution?

Copying the necessary files from the salt fileserver during module execution seems somehow wrong to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only python extensions are supported, so your best bet is to do the following:

1) Deploy your non-Python components via a `file.managed` / `file.recurse` state.

2) Ensure your custom execution module has a `__virtual__()` function checking for the existence of the non-Python dependencies, and returning `False` if they are not present. This will keep the module from being loaded and used unless the deps are present.

3) Sync your custom modules using `saltutil.sync_modules`. This function will also re-invoke the loader to update the available execution modules on the minion, so if you already had your custom module sync'ed and later deployed the non-Python depenencies, `saltutil.sync_modules` would re-load the custom modules and, provided your `__virtual__()` function returned either `True` or the desired module name, your execution module would then be available for use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess my setup is a bit uncommon for salt. The module should contain all dependencies / solve by itself the dependencies.